# Solve the recursion $a_n = a_{n-1} + n-1$ by using generating functions .

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

For $a_0 = 0$, 
solve  $a_n = a_{n-1} + n-1$.
My sequence is : 
$$
0x^0 + 0x^1+1x^2+3x^3+6x^4+10x^5+15x^6+\ldots
$$ 
Lets call that $F(x)$: now multiply $F(x)$ by $x$ and subtract the result from $F(x)$ 
$$
F(x)-F(x)\cdot x = 1\cdot x^2 + 2\cdot x^3 + 3\cdot x^4 + 4\cdot x^5 + \dots
$$
It seems that 
$$
F(x)-F(x)\cdot x=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}
$$ 
and this implies 
$$
F(x)=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3} 
$$
but could not find what to do after that ..

And the question is important because I am trying to understand the process of solving recurrence relations by using generating functions , this is not from my homework  Though I don't know how to convince you .

Comment: what did you try

Comment: This is a recurrence, not a recursion.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: Try writing out some of the terms of the sequence. Maybe there is a pattern to be found.

Comment: I have written what I tried , this is not much but please keep in mind that  I am new to this topic. @SakethMalyala

Comment: @nooneever $3$ users (including me) agree that the question shows context and an effort. I also upvoted the question since I am also interested in the way such formulas can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done, now you can use [partial fractions decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Illustration) to write
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}-\frac{2}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{1-x},
$$
and extract coefficient of each term separately. Last one is just geometric series $1+x+x^2+
\dots$ for $|x|<1$. For the other ones, notice that $\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)'=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ and $\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right)'=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$, so you can get coefficients of these by differentiating the corresponding series. Can you finish it now?

Plus, of course, you can check various questions on this site with [[generating-functions]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generating-functions) tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , But I still could not find the answer,which is n.(n-1)/2.

Comment: Tfta, But I still cant find the answer,which is n(n-1)/2. I  understood what you did though. Lets assume that we want to find a_n ; from 1/(1-x)^3 I get (n+1)(n+2)/2 , from -2/(1-x)^2 I get -2.(n+1) from 1/(1-x)  I get 1 , summing these up don't give the answer . I guess I am mistaken at the   1/(1-x)^3 part , if it is n.(n+1)/2 , which I suspect is , then everything is okay. But from my logic it should be (n+1)(n+2)/2 because when you take first derivative you get 1,2,3,4,5  , after second you get 2,6,10..... divide it by two you get 1x^0 + 2x^1 then the closed formula is (n+1)(n+2)/2

Comment: @nooneever You just summed it wrong somewhere probably, $(n+1)(n+2)/2-2(n+1)+1$ is indeed equal to $n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: yeah I see thanks a lot :)